# Jquery Regex Matching

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to find a quick and easy way to validate some inputs with jquery.  I just need to make sure that a field excepts only numerical values and only 4 integers long, basically a year.

I want to do this with jquery and can't find just a simple solution.  I'm guessing you use filter?

```
$(document).ready(function() $(input#year).filter( ) )};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different validation plugins out there that can help with this.  The first question you need to ask is whether you want to validate on `keypress` or on `blur`.  If you choose blur and you must roll your own it would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#year').blur(function() {
       var match = /\d{4}/.exec(this.value);
       if (!match) {
           alert('invalid');
       }
   }); 

});
```

I would also recommend using the `class="year"` or `$('.year')` instead of id or `$('#year')`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple plugin that allow only NUMERIC character and add maxlength="4" so the user can't type more char.

You would use it as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(input#year).numeric() ;
)};
```

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

hope this help!